# Globally set product-symbol in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{product-symbol = \ensuremath{\cdot}}
```

gives

> Package siunitx Error: Unknown option 'product-symbol'.

I'm using

> This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (MiKTeX 20.10)

on Windows 10.

[The documentation](https://packages.oth-regensburg.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) lists this example specifically on page 29.

Comment: You're looking at the documentation for version 3, but apparently you're using version 2 of siunitx. Update your MiKTeX.

Comment: @egreg thanks. This led to a new problem. Should I edit this question or open a new one?

Comment: What new problem?

Comment: @egreg Now my document compiles but the options in `\sisetup` are ignored.

Comment: I guess it's for numbers in scientific notation: look for `exponent-product` instead.

Comment: I see from your other posts that you speak German. If you just want to adhere to German conventions, setting `locale=DE` is the way to go (which will also use a `\cdot` in scientific notation).